# Git syntax for pull request on the command line

Tags: git, command-line, pull-request

I see documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull

But I'm not sure how to apply it to what I'm trying to to do. I pushed to branch called "fix/fixNumberHere" and I want to merge to a branch called "mergeBranch" using a pull request -- how to do I apply that to :

```
 git request-pull [-p] <start> <url> [<end>]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would use this syntax:

```
git request-pull mergeBranch origin fix/fixNumberHere
                 ^^^ start   ^^ url    ^^^ end
```

I think more typically most Git users would create a pull request directly on the remote, e.g. if they were using something like GitHub or BitBucket.

Comment: yes I agree about "most Git users would create a pull request directly on the remote, e.g. if they were using something like GitHub or BitBucket" .....but I'm using Gogs and it doesn't look possible.

Comment: Actually I did figure out out to initiate a Pull request in Gogs....but command line alternatives are always useful

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the remote repository, [`git request-pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) is no longer the only option: the PR can be created automatically thanks to a new server-side hook with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020):

"[`git receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c430a647cb990fc856d328733fa59e1fafadb97/Documentation/git-receive-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack))</sup> that accepts requests by "`git push`" learned to outsource most of the ref updates to the **new "`proc-receive`" hook**.

See [commit d6edc18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6edc189f6b3d8606150a52fd2c2fcd781b8550f), [commit 1702ae6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1702ae6f61412fa7d858701a7724a5cbf4aeea3e), [commit c6a6a01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6a6a01c4acae1ed4b8a61176e3346e90b298ddd), [commit 31e8595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31e8595a1132187f99792a4b889c2128cd9253ef), [commit b913075](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b913075cb8bd55a6c2ecac4aa7af0de6fb98d5b6), [commit 63518a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63518a574a3a4b8c6f152b29cb1b6d1f66f6e6c7), [commit 195d6ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/195d6eaea3b886fe13f422ce6675009ea1351224), [commit 15d3af5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15d3af5e22eceb9cd6cd341703d612a62194451e), [commit 38b9197](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38b9197a76a77671a8f48e423236739e7556c20d), [commit 917c612](https://github.com/git/git/commit/917c612512cd4523f5587870547ee5369aa4632d) (27 Aug 2020) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c430a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c430a647cb990fc856d328733fa59e1fafadb97), 25 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15d3af5e22eceb9cd6cd341703d612a62194451e): add new `proc-receive` hook
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> Git calls an internal `execute_commands` function to handle commands sent from client to `git-receive-pack`.
>
> Regardless of what references the user pushes, Git creates or updates the corresponding references if the user has write-permission.
>
> A contributor who has no write-permission, cannot push to the repository directly.
> So, the contributor has to write commits to an alternate location, and sends pull request by emails or by other ways.
> We call this workflow as a **distributed workflow**.
>
> It would be more convenient to work in a **centralized workflow** like what **Gerrit** provided for some cases.
>
> For example, a read-only user who cannot push to a branch directly can run the following [`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15d3af5e22eceb9cd6cd341703d612a62194451e/Documentation/git-push.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> command to push commits to a pseudo reference (has a prefix "`refs/for/`", not "`refs/heads/`") to create a code review.
>
> ```
> git push origin \
>     HEAD:refs/for/<branch-name>/<session>
> ```
>
> The `<branch-name>` in the above example can be as simple as "`master`", or a more complicated branch name like "`foo/bar`".
> The `<session>` in the above example command can be the local branch name of the client side, such as "`my/topic`".
>
> We cannot implement a centralized workflow elegantly by using "`pre-receive`" + "`post-receive`", because Git will call the internal function "`execute_commands`" to create references (even the special pseudo reference) between these two hooks.
> Even though we can delete the temporarily created pseudo reference via the "`post-receive`" hook, having a temporary reference is not safe for concurrent pushes.
>
> So, add a filter and a new handler to support this kind of workflow.
>
> The filter will check the prefix of the reference name, and if the command has a special reference name, the filter will turn a specific field (`run_proc_receive`) on for the command.
> Commands with this filed turned on will be executed by a new handler (a hook named "`proc-receive`") instead of the internal `execute_commands` function.
>
> **We can use this "`proc-receive`" command to create pull requests or send emails for code review**.
>
> After receiving a command, the hook will execute the command, and may create/update different reference.
>
> For example, a command for a pseudo reference "`refs/for/master/topic`" may create/update different reference such as "`refs/pull/123/head`".
> The alternate reference name and other status are given in option lines.

---

This is more robust with with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021): the exchange between `receive-pack` and `proc-receive` hook did not carefully check for errors.

See [commit 80ffeb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80ffeb94f4c9eae4e099fec47e39105fc1e19132), [commit f65003b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f65003b4c4abea49a00cc9f3d87b9f37db6b48f1), [commit cf3d868](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf3d868f353c4a5a9ecf4fbc2a44960671ba59cb) (11 Nov 2020) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8f8f10a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f8f10ac09fff0d15b74f8bded18a81d24f0127d), 25 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f65003b4c4abea49a00cc9f3d87b9f37db6b48f1): gently write messages to `proc-receive`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> Johannes found a flaky hang in `t5411/test-0013-bad-protocol.sh` in the osx-clang job of the CI/PR builds, and ran into an issue when using the `--stress` option with the following error messages:
>
> ```
> fatal: unable to write flush packet: Broken pipe
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```
>
> In this test case, the "proc-receive" hook sends an error message and dies earlier.
>
> While "receive-pack" on the other side of the pipe should forward the error message of the "proc-receive" hook to the client side, but it fails to do so.
> This is because "receive-pack" uses `packet_write_fmt()` and `packet_flush()` to write pkt-line message to "proc-receive" hook, and these functions die immediately when pipe is broken.
>
> Using "gently" forms for these functions will get more predicable output.
>
> Add more "`--die-*`" options to test helper to test different stages of the protocol between "`receive-pack`" and "`proc-receive`" hook.